# Any way to display wallpaper in app?

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, styles

My app consists of five different `fragments` where the user can slide from one to another.
I have applied the stack (Official Google Animation) to the `fragments` so the `layout` looks more appealing when transitioning from one page to another. I went ahead and made some changes, but when swiping you an see a black background so I had changed the default background in my `styles.xml` to a pre-fixed image. But I wish to apply the wallpaper of the system. For example I'm on my home-screen and I have lets say a picture of a cat as my wallpaper, and when I open my app, and scroll across screens I want the background to display the system wallpaper, aka the cat picture.

How can I go about achieving this?

I have searched on this but nothing is showing up, I've tried adding a colour item to `colors.xml` and setting the `hex value` to `#00000000` and applying this to the background, but when sliding across the `fragments`, there is no transparency, instead it's black.

It seems so I can use this code -

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

But how can I apply this as a background to all of my `fragments`? I'm aware that it must be applied in the `fragmentlauncher` class where all my fragments are launched from.

Comment: `fragment.getView().setBackground(wallpaperDrawable)` should work.

Comment: @Manu Thank you, I'm getting this now "fragment cannot be resolved"

Comment: can you please post your code where you create your fragments?

Comment: it seems to set the app background but, not the window background. Like in the styles you can set the window background from default black to anything.